# Query fast without search, slow with search, but with search fast in SSMS

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have this function that takes data from the database and also has search. The problem is that when I search with Entity framework it's slow, but if I use the same query I got from the log and use it in SSMS it's fast. I must also say that there are allot of movies, 388262. I also tried adding an index on title at movie, but didn't help.

Query I use in SSMS:

```
SELECT *
FROM Movie
WHERE title LIKE '%pirate%'
ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 30 ROWS ONLY
```

Entity code (_movieRepository.GetAll() returns Queryable not all movies):

```
public IActionResult Index(MovieIndexViewModel vm) {
    IQueryable<Movie> query = _movieRepository.GetAll().AsNoTracking();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.Search)) {
        query = query.Where(m => m.title.ToLower().Contains(vm.Search.ToLower()));
    }

    vm.TotalItemCount = query.Count();
    vm.Movies = query.Skip(_pageSize * (vm.Page - 1)).Take(_pageSize);
    vm.PageSize = _pageSize;

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Adding .AsNoTracking() doesn't make it faster either.

Comment: When I remove `vm.TotalItemCount = query.Count();` it's faster, but I need the count of the found results, how do I do this with LINQ?

Comment: In ssms if you go to tools do you have profiler.  If so can you spin up a trace and post the generated SQL.  Also when you say slow how slow do you mean.  Is it just as slow the 2nd time?

Comment: @MiniverCheevyThe I found out the it the query to retrieve the records with searching is fast, but for Count() it's also doing a query with search for the count and that one is slow, it's fast in SSMS though but not in the code. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Movie] AS [m] WHERE [m].[title] LIKE ('%Pirate%')`

Comment: I suspect it's generating more complex SQL, which is why it's slower.   I don't know if this will work in EF core but give it a try.  var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString()

Comment: Here is an article on how to view the generated SQL.  http://www.elanderson.net/2015/08/viewing-sql-for-entity-framework-7-queries/

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat: I don't have much experience with the Entity framework.*

However, you might find useful debugging tips available in the [Entity Framework Performance Article from Simple talk.](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/) Looking at what you've posted you might be able to improve your query performance by:

- Choosing only the specific column you're interested in (it sounds like you're only interested in querying for the 'Title' column).
- Pay special attention to your data-types. You might want to convert your NVARCHAR variables to VARCHAR(40) (or some appropriate character limit)

Answer (score 0):

try removing all of the ToLower() stuff,

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.Search)) {
        query = query.Where(m => m.title.Contains(vm.Search)));
    }
```

sql server (unlike c#) is not case sensitive by default (though you can configure it to be that way).  Your query is forcing sql server to lower case every record in the table and then do the comparison.